# How to approve a review on github after a review that requests changes?

Tags: github, github-codereviews

I reviewed a pull request on github and requested changes.  They made and pushed the changes.  Now I can't find a button to re-review and say "approve."  Where is it?

I also looked at [the docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-reviews).  No luck.

Comment: There is a bar that has commits, branches, packages, etc in your project. I believe what you are looking for is in branches.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the pull request, *then the "Files" tab*, and there is a green "Review changes" on the right:

[image]